# How do I find rows with an enter state without an exit state

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

so I have a table that looks like below

```
node_id    alarm_id   state   alarm_time
----------------------------------------------
108       41        enter     2019-09-14 09:20:15
108       45        exit      2019-09-13 10:20:15
108       45        enter     2019-09-13 09:20:15
108       41        exit      2019-09-12 18:00:15
108       41        enter     2019-09-12 15:20:15
```

I am trying to get all records that have an 'enter' state, but not an 'exit' state. So for the above only the first record would be returned.

I am using AWS redshift.

Thanks in advance for assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` as following:

```
select * 
  from your_table t
 where t.state = 'enter'
   and not exists
       (select 1 from your_table tin
        Where tin.node_id = t.node_id
        and tin.alarm_id = t.alarm_id
        and tin.alarm_time > t.alarm_time
        and tin.state = 'exit');
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want rows where the most recent state is `'enter'`, then you can use

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by node_id, alarm_id order by alarm_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and state = 'enter';
```

If you are looking for unbalanced rows, you can use `group by`:

```
select node_id, alarm_id
from t
group by node_id, alarm_id
having sum( (state = 'enter')::int ) > sum( (state = 'exit)::int );
```